# SSRS Expression - Show last 30 Days from Today, without changing SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have 3 tablix, each on one page. The first tablix shows result for months, the second tablix shows result for weeks and the third tablix for each day.

Now I want to limit the day-view to the last 30 days. Otherwise, it's just to much information.

The current expression for the date is `=Fields!Date.value`

Is there a way to limit the day-view to show only the last 30 days from today without changing my SQL query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This one gives me out "true" and "False"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a filter on your tablix:

[image]